# Moving data from hdfs to sql

Tags: activemq-classic, hadoop2, sqoop2, sqoop

Im testing my setup and i need to move the data in hdfs to a sql DB and that too when the data is generated. What i mean is.. once the mapreduce job is completed, it will send a ActivMQ message. I need to move it to sql automatically once i receive a ActivMQ message using Sqoop. Can some one help how to acheive this.

Can someone let me know whether MQ & Sqoop work together..?

Thank You..

Comment: Do you have microsoft BI installed on destination where SQL Server exists? I know HDFS source can be specified for data pull using SSIS

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Microsoft BI.. I never know.... I need to move data from HDFS to SQL database and that too when it arrived at a particular location(automated).

Comment: How about writing a simple batch to run every minute ? One simple approach i have used in the past is , have a file with a switch variable "switch=off". Your mapreduce job on successful completion can modify this to "swith=on".

Comment: Your batch that runs every minute can check if the variable is "On" and accordingly do a hdfs dfs -copyToLocal source destination

Comment: Thank you for the reply and sorry for late reply. So either a batch job or SSIS is the only solutions to this problem..? What about initiating a sqoop action once it receives a JMS..? Any idea..

Comment: Not too sure about SSIS since i've not used it. The batch sure does the job. Have not worked on Sqoop , so can't comment on that. Maybe others can help..

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely clear about the use-case but you can set up a Ooizie Work-Flow.The Sqoop job will only start once the map-reduce job is complete.You can actually create a complex DAG using Oozie.The Oozie work flow can inturn be invoked from a remote java client.
Hope this helped.